# Set headers for Docusign Connect

Tags: docusignapi, servicenow

Is there a way to set custom headers when using Docusign Connect? My integration (ServiceNow) requires basic authentication in addition to signing.

Comment: I believe the short answer is 'no', there is no ability to include custom x-headers/headers in the Connect payload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to set custom headers through the DocuSign Connect module, as of today.  The closest you can get to that is to include an X509 Certificate in the SOAP header, which is optional.

See the **DocuSign Connect (PDF)** doc through the [Dev Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center) -> [Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation) page for more info.